# Share @ConfigurationProperties bean in the @RestController endpoint

Tags: java, spring

I have to share my **@ConfigurationProperties** bean from my rest controller. When I just return it - the response contains fields from config, but **there are many more fields like "targetClass"** etc. (spring proxy fields) and I do not want it.
What can I do to get rid of it? Basically, I have 3 ideas:

1. Implement **DTO** that will fetch every config property - not so good because every time I will change the config - I will have to change it too.
2. Fetch real object from the proxy - walkaround, the last option that I want (and I do not know that will work).

Do you have any better ideas? Or maybe one of my offers is the only way?

Comment: The DTO route is generally considered the best way to return trimmed down objects to a client. Why would it not suit your case? You're basically always going to return the same properties of your bean, right?